# What is a good style to deploy with docker when docker hub is not available?

Tags: docker, deployment

I want to deploy my project avoiding usage of docker-hub. Is it a good idea to sent an image in tar file or just a Dockerfile combined with all local dependencies would be preferable (in this case user will need to build the image on his own)? Is there a way to deploy container itself?

Comment: Have you considered running a local Docker registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot run a local Docker Registry, then sending the image itself is preferable, as it won't force the user to access any dependencies.
Sending the Dockerfile as a complement (to document the image) is good as well.

But the main alternative is to use a [**docker registry**](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). If however you don't want to depend on local registry storage, you can use a [remote storage like S3 with minio](https://medium.com/@enne/use-minio-as-docker-registry-storage-driver-c9c72c72cc87).